# ComboBox as database navigator

Tags: sql, qt

i would like to ask u if there is a way to navigate through sql data with combobox. I want to "download" data form DB to standard item model, choose one column and use it in combobox. When user chose one name it will give me proper id in model->DB id and allow me to chose data to show.
for ex. row with bike name, built_year, wheel size etc and show only its name in combobox, when it get chosen then show rest data in table

i'm just asking is this a good way or just dead end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You can use `QSqlQueryModel` or `QSqlTableModel` to get the database data into a item model.
Than you can set the model to the combobox using `QComboBox::setModel()`.
You can choose which column display in the combobox using `QComboBox::setModelColumn()`

See [QComboBox documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html)

Comment: Your answer helps a lot. Is it possible to expose it in QML ?

Comment: Sorry but I think that it's not possible using only QML because the sql models are not available. You have to write some C++ code to expose the model to QML.

Comment: I can't use setModelColumn() in QML so propably i have to copy one row from model and use it in  QML ComboBox. It's not satify me but i don't see other way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Consider to create a proxy model to expose only the wanted column (see  [QAbstractProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html) )